# How to convert std::variant<int, string> to string

Tags: c++, string, variant

I have a `std::variant<int, std::string>`. Regardless of whether it's representing an int or string, I want to convert it to a string. The conversion from `int` to `string` is simply `std::to_string(int)`.

Currently, I use:

```
get_if<int> int_ptr{&v};  // v is a std::variant<int, std::string> and we don't know before hand which it is

string res;
if (int_ptr == nullptr) {
  res = *get_if<string>{&v};
} else {
  res = to_string(*int_ptr);
}
```

Is there a shorter approach to this?

Comment: small side note, stop using `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 7):

In C++20, you can use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) with [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) to do this

```
#include <variant>
#include <format>

int main() {
  std::variant<int, std::string> v{...};
  std::string res = std::visit([](const auto& arg) { return std::format("{}", arg); }, v);
}
```

Comment: My first time seeing `std::format`. I was looking at the doc in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format but I think I'm a bit confused how the conversion to string for `arg` is performed? How does the `"{}"` work here? This looks similar to some Python syntax for string formatting

Comment: @24n8 C++20 `std::format` mainly comes from the third-party library [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), which is similar to Python's format.

Answer (score 6):

The normal approach would be [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). Here's pseudocode off the top of my head

```
#include <string> //this has std::to_string(int)

const std::string& to_string(const std::string& s) {return s;}

...

using std::to_string;
std::string str = std::visit([](auto&& arg){return to_string(arg);}, v);
```

Comment: `std::string to_string(std::string const &input) { return input; }` was exactly the idea that occurred to me.